# Professionally sign an applet

Tags: java, security, applet, digital-signature, sign

I've made a Java applet and I self signed it before, but due to security changes in recent Java updates, self signing no longer gives the applet the necessary permissions.
I need the applet to be able to read the local file system to use images and to be able to connect to a MYSQL database.
The applet used to work with the database when I self signed it, but not anymore. 
In addition, many unknown users will be using the applet, so I won't have control over their machines.

Where can I get my applet professionally signed and if possible, is there another way to self sign that will make the applet work?

Comment: See if this [demo. of the JNLP API file services](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs) works for the problem machines (though you might wish to generate a new build showing a current date, your selected app. title/vendor, whatever..).  Report back.  It is relevant in that 1) It uses a self signed certificate 2)  It allows a sand-boxed app. to read/write to the local file system. 3) An applet launched using JWS has access to the API.

Comment: @AndrewThompson It's not a problem with the machines. No machine will be able to run it properly at this point. I think it is because I did not use `AccessController`. The demo worked fine though.

Comment: *"No machine will be able to run it properly at this point. .. The demo worked fine though."*  I thought by 'it' you meant the demo. but that ending makes me wonder if you meant 'worked fine on my machine, unable to test on problem machines yet'?  I am a little confused.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Oh sorry. I meant that no machine can run MY applet. The problem machines can run the demo though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Purchase a certificate from any reputable certificate authority. Use that to sign your code. [List of CAs](http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Security/Public_Key_Infrastructure/PKIX/Tools_and_Services/Third_Party_Certificate_Authorities/)

Or, some companies also do this: Sign the jars themselves, but pre-populate the JDK trust store with your (self created) CA cert. If you have control over the JRE that is installed on all user machines, you can place your certificate in JRE/lib/security/cacerts so that is trusted ahead of time.

**update**: This page ([Java Control Panel Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/jcp/jcp.html#security)) describes what type of signature is required for various client side security level settings:

Comment: So you are sure that self-signing no longer works? because I never used an `accesscontroller` in my code

Comment: Nope.  Didn't verify that.   But I have heard there have been changes in this area in recent releases.   For self signed certs you used to get a dialog asking if you trusted the publisher, and if so you could also select "always trust". Not sure what the current behavior is.

Comment: Ok, I'll try adding `AccessControllers` to my code and then seeing if it works.

Comment: I would be astonished if using `AccessController` could change the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the applet 'phones home' to the DB & this [demo. of the JNLP API file services](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs)<sup>1</sup> works for the problem machines you should be set to go for a Plug-In 2 JRE (1.6.0_10+) JRE.  And if the client has less than that, they should seriously look to update.  The [Deployment Toolkit Script](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html) can assist with that.

1. It is relevant in that:

   - It uses a self signed certificate
   - It allows a sand-boxed app. to read/write to the local file system.
   - An applet launched using JWS has access to the API.

*This should only be considered a work-around.  The correct way to solve the problem is to heed [the advice offered to get a certified code certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17646539/418556).  Oracle seems to be heading towards making it so that unsigned or self-signed code will not just be sand-boxed, but entirely forbidden (& that **is for the best**).*

As an aside re. DB access: For the protection of the DB. The applet should be forced to go through a 'public interface' (via the site that hosts the applet).  Do not give the applet direct access to the DB.  Otherwise hackers also have direct DB access.

Comment: Adding the `AccessController` didn't work so I'll try getting the certificate. I'll try CAcert because they give out a free one.

Comment: *"I'll try CAcert because they give out a free one."*  Do they?!  At what URL can we find/apply for these certificates?  I've wanted a free cert. to play with since the Thawte 'FreeeMail' certificates were offered (seemingly for a very short time - was slack & missed out).

Comment: I think the reason the JNLP you told me to try is because it's a JNLP. I actually have an embedded applet in an html page, so I think (not sure) that JNLPs don't have the same restrictions as normal applets.

Comment: Never mind, the applet is able to read the file system after I used a different way of accessing it. I used `back2 = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "blank_blue.png"); ` now and it works

Comment: Do you know of any self signed applets that can access a database?

Comment: Nevermind once again. The reason images show up now is because they are packaged inside the jar. What functions do you use to read those that are outside the jar?